# How to work over rows from all other sheets in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-filter, regex

I have a 'summary' sheet and 12 other sheets named 'Jan20', 'Feb20', etc.

In the summary sheet I have this formula (to calculate Uber costs):

```
=FILTER('Jan20'!F2:F, REGEXMATCH('Jan20'!D2:D, "UBER"))
```

How do I make it automatically span over the *rest* of the sheets instead of just Jan20?

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Answer (score 0):

- to span horizontally, paste this formula where you need it and drag to the right:

  ```
  =FILTER(    INDIRECT(TEXT(EOMONTH("01/01/2019", COLUMN(A1)-2)+20, "mmmdd")&"!F2:F"), 
   REGEXMATCH(INDIRECT(TEXT(EOMONTH("01/01/2019", COLUMN(A1)-2)+20, "mmmdd")&"!D2:D"),
   "UBER"))
  ```
- to span vertically, paste this formula where you need it and drag it down:

  ```
  =FILTER(    INDIRECT(TEXT(EOMONTH("01/01/2019", ROW(A1)-2)+20, "mmmdd")&"!F2:F"), 
   REGEXMATCH(INDIRECT(TEXT(EOMONTH("01/01/2019", ROW(A1)-2)+20, "mmmdd")&"!D2:D"),
   "UBER"))
  ```

Comment: Is this the correct answer? The question is about spanning across sheets (in the formula variables), not across rows or columns.

Comment: from your question was understood that you are located at "summary" sheet and in that sheet you need to create a summary of each of the 12 sheets and span it over "summary" sheet in such way that you wouldn't need to copy-paste sheets' references/names eg. edit 12 different formulas 12 times.

Answer (score 0):

I finally arrived at my own solution using the extremely handy `query` function in combination with the array range selector:

```
=query({'Jan20'!A2:F;'Feb20'!A2:F;'Mar20'!A2:F}, "select Col1,Col4,Col6 where Col4 contains 'UBER' and Col1 is not NULL")
```

I still have to manually add in the new months (there is only 12 of them per document anyway), but it is much simpler than the original formula.